# Oracle Database, how to view or change nchar set

Tags: oracle

Hello from Greece and Merry Xmas to everyone.
We got an outsourcing plant designing job and the customer wants it in Oracle DB. Design will take place within the next 3 months and afterwards will deliver the DB to customer.
He asked these 3 particular specs for Oracle:

1. Oracle - 12cR1--->Done, purchased 10 licenses, located this particular version and installed.
2. Oracle DB character set – AL32UTF8 ---> Done, selected this while creating DB
3. NCHAR character set– AL16UTF16 ---> This is my problem. How can i view the NCHAR of the database that i have created? I have SQL developer also installed as a tool.

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT * 
FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS 
WHERE PARAMETER IN ('NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET')
```

If you need to change: For a new database, just drop the entire DB and create a new one from scratch. Otherwise follow the [Character Set Migration](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch11charsetmig.htm#NLSPG011) - however, `AL16UTF16` is the default for national character, actually I don't see any reason to change it.

Comment: Thank you so much. Just to clarify, is this the query which when i run it shows me the NCHAR of db? In other words, is it a query to view only?

Comment: What else would you expect from a "SELECT" statement ?

Comment: Dear Wernfried, i would expect all the best for you and best wishes. Thank you indeed for your help.